# Execute python function with boost-python (not global scope statements)

Tags: c++, boost-python

I've a question regarding boost-python. Basically I want to execute a specific python function which is stored in a std::string with boost-python. There is an example how to achieve this in the documentation: [Boost python doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/python/doc/v2/exec.html#eval-spec).

So what I'm doing is (C++ Code):

```
using namespace boost::python;
Py_Initialize();

// Retrieve the main module.
object main = import("__main__");

// Retrieve the main module's namespace
object global(main.attr("__dict__"));

// Define greet function in Python.
object result = exec(string_with_python_code.c_str(), global, global);

object greet = global["greet"];

//calling greet() function
greet();

Py_Finalize();
```

However, this also executes the code which is not in the function but in the global scope (contrary to the statement in the documentation where it says above the exec() statement: "[only] **Define** greet function in Python").

For example if I set the python code in string_with_python_code like this:

```
string_with_python_code = "print 'Hello global world!'    \n"
                          "                               \n"
                          "def greet():                   \n"
                          "    print 'Hello local world!' \n"
                          "    return                     \n";
```

Then the sentence "Hello global world!" is also printed out (before "Hello local world!" is printed out).

However, what I hoped to accomplish is that only the function greet() gets executed. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Python function definition is an execution of Python code. So is a Python module import: importing a module can cause arbitrary Python statements to run.

The way to not run code outside your function definition is to not pass code outside your function definition to `exec`. `exec` will do exactly what you tell it to do, no less.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in global scope will be executed if you import python module either using interpreter or Python C API / BOOST Python.
Thats how python works.

To fix this add this before global scope:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Example:

```
*script.py*

def local():
    print "local"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "global"
```

If you execute script only "global" will be printed. If you import this module nothing will be printed.